# How to exclude a dependency for a flavor in gradle

Tags: android, gradle

We an android projects with lots of flavors.   One flavor includes an aar that bundles android-async-http inside the aar file.

The problem is we already define the compile dependency for all our flavors:

```
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6'
```

and that results in failed builds with the error:

```
 > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: 
duplicate entry: com/loopj/android/http/AssertUtils.class
```

I'm looking to try to exclude that dependency for just one flavor.  Something like:

```
freeCompile('com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.6') {
    exclude = true
}
```

Anyway to do that without defining the dependency for every flavor?